# Silverstripe 4.6 create/save Image-Object from url

Tags: image, object, url, silverstripe-4

How can we create a has_one Image relation on a DataObject, and save this Image from a given URL to this DataObject?

What I have tried:

```
class VideoObject extends DataObject
{

 private static $has_one = [
    'AutoThumbnail' => Image::class 
   ];

private static $owns = [
        'AutoThumbnail'
    ];

public function onAfterWrite() { 
        parent::onAfterWrite();
        $this->imagetest();
    }
    
    
    public function imagetest(){
        
        $folder = Folder::find_or_make('Uploads');
        $imageSource = $this->EmbedThumbnailURL; // == ( https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1Rhq53sCfRU/maxresdefault.jpg )
        $sourcePath = pathinfo($imageSource);
        $fileName = basename($this->EmbedThumbnailURL);
        $image = new Image();

        $pic = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($imageSource));  
        imagejpeg($pic, 'assets/'.$fileName);
        $image->ParentID = $folder->ID;
           
        $image->FileFilename = $fileName;
        $image->Name = $fileName;
        $image->write();
        $this->AutoThumbnailID = $this->ID;
        $image->doPublish();
        $this->AutoThumbnail()->$image;
}
```

Here something goes wrong with Folder, and the Path to the Folder, the Image doesn't display correct (a red square) in Files - Section, also doesn't display in template.
WHAT am I doing wrong?
Could you provide me a working Example?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To get an image from URL you can use [File::setFromString](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/files/file_management/#creating-files-in-php). It will do all the stuff for you. So in your case you can have something like:

```
$image = new Image();
$image->setFromString(file_get_contents($imageSource), $fileName);
$imageID = $image->write();
```

Then you need to assign its ID to your VideoObject:

```
$this->AutoThumbnailID = $imageID;
```

After this you have to save/write VideoObject to preserve changes and when you move $this->imagetest() from onAfterWrite to onBeforeWrite it will be done automatically (personally, I do not think having it in onAfterWrite is the luckiest thing).